# How to conditionally render HTML input elements based on a string value that specifies its element type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am building a form using an `array` of `objects` that describe the elements within the form.

```
const fields = [
  { name: "Name", type: "text", placeholder: "What's your fullname?" },
  { name: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "We promise not to spam you." },
  { name: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "Make it a good one!" },
  { name: "About", type: "textarea", placeholder: "Tell us a little about yourself ..." },
];
```

I map over each object to produce my form which all works as desired.

```
{fields.map((field, index) => (
    <div key={form-field-${index}`}>
        <label htmlFor={field.name}>{field.name}</label>
        <div>
            {field.type !== "textarea" &&
                <input
                    type={field.type}
                    id={field.name}
                    name={field.name}
                    placeholder={field.placeholder}
                />
            }
            {field.type === "textarea" &&
                <textarea
                    id={field.name}
                    name={field.name}
                    placeholder={field.placeholder}
                />
            }
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

As you can see I have some conditional rendering based on the `type` value of each `field`. For two different form elements this is not horrendous, but if I go adding other form elements (`<select>` for example), I would prefer to not have `x` conditionals if there is a better alternative.

Is there a better alternative? Move this to its a function, or its own component perhaps?

I am kind of hoping there is a means of doing something like:

```
{fields.map((field, index) => {
  <field.formType
    id="{field.name}"
    ...
    />
});
```

Where `field.formType` maps to a `formType: "input"` in the `fields` array.

Comment: You can you a function with a switch statement

Comment: A switch or an object with a key of `input type` and a value of `component function` would my go-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually do this if you assign it to a capitalised variable then use that (is a weird JSX gotcha). See https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized.

```
{fields.map((field, index) => {
  const Tag = field.formType
  return <Tag 
    id={field.name}
    ...
    />
});
```

Comment: Wow that's amazing! I haven't seen this in any project out there. 
This is so helpful.

Comment: This is ideal and just what I was looking for. Need to adjust it for use in my `TS` React project (chucking type safety errors), but that is a **me** problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would say create separate components for each type of input (input, textarea, select, etc.) and keep using conditionals:

```js
{fields.map((field, index) => (
    <div key={form-field-${index}`}>
        <label htmlFor={field.name}>{field.name}</label>
        <div>
            {field.type === "text" && <Input field={field} />}
            {field.type === "email" && <Input field={field} />}
            {field.type === "password" && <Input field={field} />}
            {field.type === "textarea" && <Textarea field={field} />}
            {field.type === "select" && <Select field={field} />}
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

or if you can change the structure of the data in the array, add a property like `formType` and use that to define which component to use:

```js
{fields.map((field, index) => (
    <div key={form-field-${index}`}>
        <label htmlFor={field.name}>{field.name}</label>
        <div>
            {field.formType === "input" && <Input field={field} />}
            {field.formType === "textarea" && <Textarea field={field} />}
            {field.formType === "select" && <Select field={field} />}
        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

It's clean and you can use individual logic/state/etc. inside each component if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a new field (property) like Component to your array of fields and there you can have anything you like, like Component:input, Component:select, Component: CustomComponent and then  when mapping you render that component and provide other fields as props
like: (inside map here)

```
const {Component, ...props} = field;

return <Component {...props}/>
```

note that for select you might need to create a custom component that when receives options as props knows how to handle them since select takes options as children and not as attributes (props)